# Google Script Automatic Range Protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I want users to enter information freely then "submit" their data. Once they "submit" this data I would like to protect a specific range where all other users cannot edit any data within that range with the exception of the owner; but still have the ability to view and access this data for reference.

I have tried this a couple ways and keep running into various obstacles. I am not very familiar with google script but am finding this is the only way to accomplish this automatically with little maintenance. Doing so, I have ran into two main obstacles:

The first one being the script that is being run is protecting the range based on a cell value. If the cell value of N7 is "Approved" it is supposed to protect the range. What is happening is the script is protecting the range regardless of what the cell value is (the value can be blank or a different word and it will still protect the range).

The second issue is, if I have the script run off of a "button" or recorded macro, the script will not remove the editor clicking the button. So with this issue, I (the owner) would need to go in every time to click the button to remove all editors.

The current script that I have right now is listed below. This script is to perform the protection based off the cell value in N7 on open:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var approvedCellD1 = spreadsheet.getRange('N7').getValue();
  var rangeD1 = spreadsheet.getRange('B5:L64');
  var protectionD1 = rangeD1.protect().setDescription('Day 1 Approved');

  if(approvedCellD1 == "Approved") {
    protectionD1.removeEditors(protectionD1.getEditors());
    protectionD1.addEditor(['myemail@gmail.com']);
    if (protectionD1.canDomainEdit()) {
      protectionD1.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  }
};
```

I made a similar version of the spreadsheet it with the main components and still receive the same issues.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NReUL2GSNWjMGrzvskQx86JDWox3e2wzDpk3PnKGX4/edit?usp=sharing

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or advice that I can try!! I have been searching and modifying my scripts for almost 2 months now and am still experiencing difficulties.

THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Using Logger.log, have you tested if your variable approvedCellD1 has a value Approved if you indeed set it to Approve? Set it to Approve and execute your function to check N7 value.

Comment: Thank you for your input!! I just used Logger.log and the log results for N7 were: "[18-06-19 09:25:22:395 PDT] Approved".   So I think its reading the value properly (I've never used Logger.log before).  Same results though, still protecting the range regardless of the value of N7.